# I am trying to write an htaccess file performs authentication and redirects authenticated users to authorized directories. Can anyone help me with the condition syntax?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, htpasswd, regular-expressions

This is what I have so far but I can't get the RewriteCond and RewriteRule properly.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (\d{3})$ 
RewriteRule !^%1 http://subdomain.mydomain.com/%1 [R,L].

AuthName "My Domain Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

This is what I mean the `ReWriteCond and RewriteRule` to say:

"If the REMOTE_USER has a username ending in 3 digits then capture the three digits that match and for whatever url they are trying to access if it does not start with the 3 digits captured then redirect them to the sub directory with the name equal to those captured three digits."

In other words, if a user named 'johnny202' is authenticated then if he's requesting any directory other than http://subdomain.mydomain.com/202/ then he should be redirected to http://subdomain.mydomain.com/202/

The only thing I can think of that is wrong is the first instance of '%1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to remember with mod_rewrite - it matches the rule **before** looking at the conditions, so at the time it checks the rule pattern, it hasn't run any of the conditions, and hasn't set up the %1 backreference yet. I'd try separating the URL check into a second condition - something like the following

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} ([0-9]{3})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/%1 [R,L].
```

This way, the rule will match every request, so the conditions will always be examined, but the redirect should only happen where the request doesn't begin with the "correct" number.

N.b. I've taken out the LA-U in the first condition - as I understand it, you don't need that if it's in a .htaccess file (only if the rewrite is in the main Apache config).

Comment: N.b. I haven't tested this, so you may need to play with it a bit to get it working.

Comment: I didn't know it matches the rule before looking at the condition. This explains so much. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem - it confused me for a while until I set RewriteLogLevel to something fairly high to really see what was going on (which of course you can't do in a .htaccess file)